# ASP.NET MVC : Calling Different View

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, view

I have a controller located in Controllers folder.

```
Controllers
          .... CustomViewController
```

The CustomViewController executes the following method

```
 public ActionResult DisplayPerson()
    {
        Person prn = new Person();
        prn.Name = "Rama";
        prn.Email = "Jass@yahoo.com";
        return View(prn);
    }
```

I have two views located in CustomView folder

```
Views
     ....CustomView
         .. DisplayPerson
         .. PersonView2
```

Routing

```
routes.MapRoute(
                  "Display",
                  "{Controller}/{action}/{id}",
                   new { controller = "CustomView", 
                   action = "DisplayPerson", id = "" }
               );
```

**Question :**

By default the view "DisplayPerson" is used to display the Person details.What is the 
way to call the view  "PersonView2" inside the "DisplayPerson()" method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
return View("DisplayPerson", prn)
```

or

```
return View("PersonView2", prn)
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460310.aspx

Comment: If you don't give a view name, MVC defaults to a view named for the Action, but this is just a *default*.